# How to make Gmail atom feed show all emails in a conversation, or the last email in a conversation

Tags: gmail, rss, feeds, atom

I'm trying to use the [Gmail Inbox Feed](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed).

The URL to the Gmail feed is https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom.

My problem is that it doesn't seem like it shows  new emails if they are grouped  into an existing conversation. The feed is only showing the **oldest** email from each conversation.  I want to see all the latest emails I received in my inbox. Curiously, the `<issued>` tag shows the date and time of the newest email even though the email in that containing `<entry>` tag is an old one.

If you want to reproduce this problem yourself: send an email to yourself, then reply to that email with a different message so that both emails show up in the same conversation. Then mark them **both** as unread by clicking the dropdown arrow on the **oldest** email and then clicking "Mark unread from here". If you go to the feed URL above, it will only show the first email you sent to yourself.

Is there a setting or parameter that I can set in order for the feed to show all latest emails? Or at least the **newest** email in each conversation?

I tried turning "Conversation View" off at `Settings > General` but that didn't solve my problem.